# Pourquoi « maintenant » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, histoire

En français, on utilise le mot « maintenant » pour désigner le présent. Je dirais que ce mot est une conjugaison de « maintenir », un mot issu de « main » et « tenir ». Ainsi, le français est la seule langue que je connais qui bricole un tel mot à partir de deux autres mots. Les langues étrangères utilisent des mots brefs comme *nu, now, jetzt, nå, nunc*.

Est-ce qu’un mot pareil a eu cours en français. Et si oui, pourquoi a-t-il disparu pour être remplacé par « maintenant » ?

Comment: Le français n'est pas seul! Par exemple, [*ahora*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ahora) en espagnol vient de agora, forme désuète dérivée du latin hac hora (« à cette heure-ci »). Idem pour le portugais *agora*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les mots étrangers cités ici descendent tous du latin "*nunc*" signifiant "*maintenant*". La langue française n'a pas (plus ?) de mots français basés sur *nunc* voulant dire maintenant. Les seules traces de *nunc* que l'on retrouve en français sont dans des expressions tirées du latin : "*hic et nunc*" (ici et maintenant), "*nunc est bibendum*" (c'est maintenant qu'il faut boire)…

Étymologiquement, "maintenant" [viendrait de l'expression latine "*manu tenedo*"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/maintenant). Un scénario possible est donc que "*manu tenedo*" ait eu une synonymie avec "*nunc*" à un moment donné de l'Histoire (à l'époque des Romains ou bien plus tard) et que le français a finalement retenu "*manu tenedo*" plutôt que "*nunc*" pour des raisons qui nous échappent.

Ce n'est pas parce que le français descend du latin que tous ses mots doivent fortement ressembler au latin signifiant la même chose. Un bel exemple est le mot "*tête*" qui vient du "*testa*" latin signifiant "*marmite*". Même si on l'a retrouvé dans de nombreux mots par la suite, ce n'est donc pas "*capita*" qui a été choisi mais l'un de ses synonymes familiers. Peut-être est-ce le cas pour "*manu tenedo*" ?

À noter qu'on retrouve aussi le "*tenedo*" latin de "*manu tenedo*" dans l'expression française "*séance tenante*" qui est un synonyme éloigné de "*maintenant*". Peut-être a-t-on là la clé du mystère, qui sait ?

Answer (score 3):

En ancien français et jusqu'au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle environ *or* était le seul mot employé pour dire ce que nous exprimons de nos jours en français par « maintenant ».

***Or*** du latin tardif *ha hora*, du latin classique *hac hora* (littéralement « à cette heure », même origine  que le mot [espagnol actuel](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ahora) qui signifie « maintenant ».

Parallèlement en ancien français existait l'expression *manutenire* (du latin
 *manu tenendo*), qui signifiait « pendant que l’on tient quelque chose dans la main » d'où l'idée de proximité spatiale qui a abouti au sens « aussitôt, immédiatement ». Cette expression a donné « **maintenant** » qui a commencé à prendre sons sens actuel au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle.
*Or* et et *maintenant* ont co-existé pour signifier« au moment présent »  jusqu'à la disparition complète de *or* dans ce sens au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle.
En même temps *or* a pris son sens actuel en tant que conjonction de coordination.

Tout ceci est très résumé et ceux que ça intéresse pourront lire [cette thèse de master](http://lib.ugent.be/fulltxt/RUG01/001/786/635/RUG01-001786635_2012_0001_AC.pdf) d'un étudiant de l'université de Gand (*Gent*). Le sujet a été très étudié mais je pense que cette étude d'un néerlandophone qui comporte des références à l'anglais et à l'allemand, s'imposait *hic et nunc*.

Comment: Il y a une petite erreur. *Or* dans le sens de *maintenant* n'a pas totalement disparu. Il est encore présent dans l'expression "*d'ores et déjà*".

Comment: @air-dex Ce n'est pas une ereur. Il n'est présent **que dans**  cette locution et les lisguistes disent que **or* a disparu dans le sens de maintenant.